# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery, url, webmethod

What is the problem, call to service is working fine when its local but when its online its shows    `Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration` One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.

It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a sub domain of one of the App's domains in console log?

Code:

```
 function CallService(serviceurl) {
         alert(serviceurl);
         $.ajax({
                 Type: "GET", 
                 contentType: "html",
                 url: serviceurl,
                 success: function (arg) {
                          console.log(arg);
                          if (arg != "") {
                          if (arg == "nodata") {
                          console.log(arg); 
                          chkData = false;
                          $('#loading').empty(); return; } 
                          $("#dynamiccontainer").append(arg);
                          chckGamesDisplayed = false; } $('#loading').empty();
                         } 
                      }
           );}
```

Comment: Could you so us some source code?

Comment: i am getting correct service url but call to service success is not happening but in local its working fine

Comment: can you provide your URL for both local anf online

Comment: if url is separetly called its shows data, but its showing error when called with ajax call

Comment: what there in `serviceurl`

Comment: didnt got from ur last comment?

Comment: In alert(serviceurl); what you get ??

Answer (score 2):

earlier i was using
var serviceurl = document.getElementById('hfbasicurl').value + "/Pages/abc.aspx?Id=" + id;

using the below code , its working fine now

```
var serviceurl = "Pages/abc.aspx?Id=" + id;
```